# youtub-dl work in command line bot not work in php

Tags: php, cookies, youtube-dl

it works when I use `youtube-dl --cookies cookies.txt --get-url $url` in LINUX terminal.

but it dose not work when I use `exec("youtube-dl --cookies cookies.txt --get-url $url");` in PHP.

and it work when I delete `--cookies cookies.txt` from code.

return : [youtube] yIRBMRTb260: Downloading webpage

ERROR: yIRBMRTb260: YouTube said: Unable to extract video data

help please.

Comment: is cookie.txt in same folder as php script ?

what error does it return ?

Comment: Have you tried to use the full path to `YOUTUBE-dl`?

Comment: How you know it does not work? Any output? Errors?

Comment: i use this in bot and just return this [youtube] yIRBMRTb260: Downloading webpage . and yes the text file is in same folder

Comment: my youtube-dl said it can not be downloaded: ` youtube-dl --get-url https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yIRBMRTb260
ERROR: yIRBMRTb260: YouTube said: Unable to extract video data`

Comment: i think this video has age limited @GoliyMuzhik

Comment: @kerbh0lz this command without --cookie worked. but when add --cookie dosent work. I do not think the problem is for path

Comment: The sample ID (yIRBMRTb260) is from a restricted Adult video... so in console mode, without cookie, it don't work also.  your problem seem ti be in your cookie.txt... are you sure to use the same "cookie.txt" file  in console mode and in the php script ?

Comment: i can confirm, i have a try 1/ create a cookies.txt  2/ using your url sample... and it work, in console and in a php script. one think: be sure to have a youtube-dl updated ! (use youtube-dl -U command for this)

Comment: For more information...youtube-dl change the cookies.txt file, so it must be writable

Comment: @Mirabeau yes cookie.text is one file

Comment: @Mirabeau youtube-dl is updated